# strange issue: ASPX page showing javascript content as text

Tags: asp.net, browser, bandwidth

On one user's machine an ASPX page suddenly showed JavaScript code as text on the page. The original contents of the page were also showing half baked and broken. The user was using IE browser.  Though I cannot post the contents of the page here, I will try to describe it as accurately as I can. In between the address bar and the actual beginning of the page, there was a cross-section showing some JavaScript text. The text appears to be the automatic JavaScript that is generated by ASP .NET for Validators. The JavaScript text, it seems is of the Validators used inside a User Control that is used on this page.
This issue has happened just one-off. Now the page is showing OK to the same user.
Though I am sure this must have been a bandwidth issue I have no evidence to  prove this and nor able to regenerate the issue. And 'someone' claims that this might have been a hacking attempt. 
Has anyone faced similar issue ? Is there anyway to conclusively prove that this to be a bandwidth issue and has nothing to do with code or anything on the server ?

Comment: Maybe was a javascript injection, but the control renders it correctly as text and not run it.

Comment: That was my first thought but I checked the contents and verified it was not.